# C++: free(): invalid next size (fast)

Tags: c++, linux

I want to go through a vector of string and split each string by space. but it throws an error, 
I use print to find the error:

```
for(int client_i=0; client_i<l.size();client_i++){
    ...
}
```

The error does not occur in client_i=0, as it can print out all successfully message once, but I am sure the vector size is 2, so it should print all successfully message twice.

```
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x81609)[0x7f05ad207609]
/lib64/libstdc++.so.6(_ZNSsD1Ev+0x43)[0x7f05adb28b63]
./assignment1[0x404d8a]
./assignment1[0x4044ba]
./assignment1[0x403d17]
./assignment1[0x403477]
./assignment1[0x402e46]
./assignment1[0x40645c]
./assignment1[0x406017]
./assignment1[0x4065ee]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x7f05ad1a8495]
./assignment1[0x401e79]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00409000 r-xp 00000000 00:2a 49026461                           /home/csdue/yichenwa/cse489589_assignment1/yichenwa/assignment1
00609000-0060a000 rw-p 00009000 00:2a 49026461                           /home/csdue/yichenwa/cse489589_assignment1/yichenwa/assignment1
00c43000-00c64000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7f05a8000000-7f05a8021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f05a8021000-7f05ac000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f05acb53000-7f05acb69000 r-xp 00000000 08:08 1835074                    /usr/lib64/libresolv-2.17.so
7f05acb69000-7f05acd68000 ---p 00016000 08:08 1835074                    /usr/lib64/libresolv-2.17.so
7f05acd68000-7f05acd69000 r--p 00015000 08:08 1835074                    /usr/lib64/libresolv-2.17.so
7f05acd69000-7f05acd6a000 rw-p 00016000 08:08 1835074                    /usr/lib64/libresolv-2.17.so
7f05acd6a000-7f05acd6c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f05acd6c000-7f05acd71000 r-xp 00000000 08:08 1835062                    /usr/lib64/libnss_dns-2.17.so
7f05acd71000-7f05acf71000 ---p 00005000 08:08 1835062                    /usr/lib64/libnss_dns-2.17.so
7f05acf71000-7f05acf72000 r--p 00005000 08:08 1835062                    /usr/lib64/libnss_dns-2.17.so
7f05acf72000-7f05acf73000 rw-p 00006000 08:08 1835062                    /usr/lib64/libnss_dns-2.17.so
7f05acf73000-7f05acf7f000 r-xp 00000000 08:08 1835064                    /usr/lib64/libnss_files-2.17.so
7f05acf7f000-7f05ad17e000 ---p 0000c000 08:08 1835064                    /usr/lib64/libnss_files-2.17.so
7f05ad17e000-7f05ad17f000 r--p 0000b000 08:08 1835064                    /usr/lib64/libnss_files-2.17.so
7f05ad17f000-7f05ad180000 rw-p 0000c000 08:08 1835064                    /usr/lib64/libnss_files-2.17.so
7f05ad180000-7f05ad186000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f05ad186000-7f05ad348000 r-xp 00000000 08:08 1835046                    /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so
7f05ad348000-7f05ad548000 ---p 001c2000 08:08 1835046                    /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so
7f05ad548000-7f05ad54c000 r--p 001c2000 08:08 1835046                    /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so
7f05ad54c000-7f05ad54e000 rw-p 001c6000 08:08 1835046                    /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so
7f05ad54e000-7f05ad553000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f05ad553000-7f05ad568000 r-xp 00000000 08:08 1850415                    /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-4.8.5-20150702.so.1
7f05ad568000-7f05ad767000 ---p 00015000 08:08 1850415                    /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-4.8.5-20150702.so.1
7f05ad767000-7f05ad768000 r--p 00014000 08:08 1850415                    /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-4.8.5-20150702.so.1
7f05ad768000-7f05ad769000 rw-p 00015000 08:08 1850415                    /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-4.8.5-20150702.so.1
7f05ad769000-7f05ad86a000 r-xp 00000000 08:08 1835054                    /usr/lib64/libm-2.17.so
7f05ad86a000-7f05ada69000 ---p 00101000 08:08 1835054                    /usr/lib64/libm-2.17.so
7f05ada69000-7f05ada6a000 r--p 00100000 08:08 1835054                    /usr/lib64/libm-2.17.so
7f05ada6a000-7f05ada6b000 rw-p 00101000 08:08 1835054                    /usr/lib64/libm-2.17.so
7f05ada6b000-7f05adb54000 r-xp 00000000 08:08 1835336                    /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.19
7f05adb54000-7f05add53000 ---p 000e9000 08:08 1835336                    /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.19
7f05add53000-7f05add5b000 r--p 000e8000 08:08 1835336                    /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.19
7f05add5b000-7f05add5d000 rw-p 000f0000 08:08 1835336                    /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.19
7f05add5d000-7f05add72000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f05add72000-7f05add94000 r-xp 00000000 08:08 1850417                    /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so
7f05adf8a000-7f05adf93000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f05adf93000-7f05adf94000 r--p 00021000 08:08 1850417                    /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so
7f05adf94000-7f05adf95000 rw-p 00022000 08:08 1850417                    /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so
7f05adf95000-7f05adf96000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffe298ca000-7ffe298eb000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffe29937000-7ffe29939000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
Abort
```

I run valgrind --leak-check=yes to check..and this is the result: 
It is hard to understand :(

```
valgrind --leak-check=yes ./assignment1 c 3434
==15589== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==15589== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==15589== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==15589== Command: ./assignment1 c 3434
==15589== 
==15589== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==15589==    at 0x4019BD3: index (in /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so)
==15589==    by 0x4007510: expand_dynamic_string_token (in /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so)
==15589==    by 0x400799C: fillin_rpath (in /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so)
==15589==    by 0x40082D8: _dl_init_paths (in /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so)
==15589==    by 0x4003466: dl_main (in /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so)
==15589==    by 0x4017F2D: _dl_sysdep_start (in /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so)
==15589==    by 0x4001BB0: _dl_start (in /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so)
==15589==    by 0x4001127: ??? (in /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so)
==15589==    by 0x2: ???
==15589==    by 0xFFF000442: ???
==15589==    by 0xFFF000450: ???
==15589==    by 0xFFF000452: ???
==15589== 
==15589== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==15589==    at 0x4019BE2: index (in /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so)
==15589==    by 0x4007510: expand_dynamic_string_token (in /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so)
==15589==    by 0x400799C: fillin_rpath (in /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so)
==15589==    by 0x40082D8: _dl_init_paths (in /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so)
==15589==    by 0x4003466: dl_main (in /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so)
==15589==    by 0x4017F2D: _dl_sysdep_start (in /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so)
==15589==    by 0x4001BB0: _dl_start (in /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so)
==15589==    by 0x4001127: ??? (in /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so)
==15589==    by 0x2: ???
==15589==    by 0xFFF000442: ???
==15589==    by 0xFFF000450: ???
==15589==    by 0xFFF000452: ???
==15589== 
==15589== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==15589==    at 0x4019BF1: index (in /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so)
==15589==    by 0x4007510: expand_dynamic_string_token (in /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so)
==15589==    by 0x400799C: fillin_rpath (in /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so)
==15589==    by 0x40082D8: _dl_init_paths (in /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so)
==15589==    by 0x4003466: dl_main (in /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so)
==15589==    by 0x4017F2D: _dl_sysdep_start (in /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so)
==15589==    by 0x4001BB0: _dl_start (in /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so)
==15589==    by 0x4001127: ??? (in /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so)
==15589==    by 0x2: ???
==15589==    by 0xFFF000442: ???
==15589==    by 0xFFF000450: ???
==15589==    by 0xFFF000452: ???
==15589== 
==15589== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==15589==    at 0x4019B90: index (in /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so)
==15589==    by 0x4007510: expand_dynamic_string_token (in /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so)
==15589==    by 0x40084DC: _dl_map_object (in /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so)
==15589==    by 0x400130D: map_doit (in /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so)
==15589==    by 0x400F703: _dl_catch_error (in /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so)
==15589==    by 0x4001DE9: handle_ld_preload (in /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so)
==15589==    by 0x40042A1: dl_main (in /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so)
==15589==    by 0x4017F2D: _dl_sysdep_start (in /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so)
==15589==    by 0x4001BB0: _dl_start (in /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so)
==15589==    by 0x4001127: ??? (in /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so)
==15589==    by 0x2: ???
==15589==    by 0xFFF000442: ???
==15589== 
==15589== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==15589==    at 0x4019B9F: index (in /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so)
==15589==    by 0x4007510: expand_dynamic_string_token (in /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so)
==15589==    by 0x40084DC: _dl_map_object (in /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so)
==15589==    by 0x400130D: map_doit (in /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so)
==15589==    by 0x400F703: _dl_catch_error (in /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so)
==15589==    by 0x4001DE9: handle_ld_preload (in /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so)
==15589==    by 0x40042A1: dl_main (in /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so)
==15589==    by 0x4017F2D: _dl_sysdep_start (in /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so)
==15589==    by 0x4001BB0: _dl_start (in /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so)
==15589==    by 0x4001127: ??? (in /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so)
==15589==    by 0x2: ???
==15589==    by 0xFFF000442: ???
==15589== 
==15589== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==15589==    at 0x4019BAE: index (in /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so)
==15589==    by 0x4007510: expand_dynamic_string_token (in /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so)
==15589==    by 0x40084DC: _dl_map_object (in /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so)
==15589==    by 0x400130D: map_doit (in /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so)
==15589==    by 0x400F703: _dl_catch_error (in /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so)
==15589==    by 0x4001DE9: handle_ld_preload (in /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so)
==15589==    by 0x40042A1: dl_main (in /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so)
==15589==    by 0x4017F2D: _dl_sysdep_start (in /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so)
==15589==    by 0x4001BB0: _dl_start (in /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so)
==15589==    by 0x4001127: ??? (in /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so)
==15589==    by 0x2: ???
==15589==    by 0xFFF000442: ???
==15589== 
==15589== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==15589==    at 0x4C2BA1C: strcpy (vg_replace_strmem.c:506)
==15589==    by 0x40628D: hostname_Client() (client.cpp:221)
==15589==    by 0x4057E2: setup_Client(int) (client.cpp:55)
==15589==    by 0x4065F5: main (yichenwa_assignment1.cpp:77)
==15589== 
==15589== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==15589==    at 0x4C2BA47: is_overlap (vg_replace_strmem.c:128)
==15589==    by 0x4C2BA47: strcpy (vg_replace_strmem.c:506)
==15589==    by 0x40628D: hostname_Client() (client.cpp:221)
==15589==    by 0x4057E2: setup_Client(int) (client.cpp:55)
==15589==    by 0x4065F5: main (yichenwa_assignment1.cpp:77)
==15589== 
==15589== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==15589==    at 0x4C2BA53: is_overlap (vg_replace_strmem.c:137)
==15589==    by 0x4C2BA53: strcpy (vg_replace_strmem.c:506)
==15589==    by 0x40628D: hostname_Client() (client.cpp:221)
==15589==    by 0x4057E2: setup_Client(int) (client.cpp:55)
==15589==    by 0x4065F5: main (yichenwa_assignment1.cpp:77)
==15589== 
==15589== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==15589==    at 0x4C2BAB8: is_overlap (vg_replace_strmem.c:140)
==15589==    by 0x4C2BAB8: strcpy (vg_replace_strmem.c:506)
==15589==    by 0x40628D: hostname_Client() (client.cpp:221)
==15589==    by 0x4057E2: setup_Client(int) (client.cpp:55)
==15589==    by 0x4065F5: main (yichenwa_assignment1.cpp:77)
==15589== 
==15589== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==15589==    at 0x4C2BA62: strcpy (vg_replace_strmem.c:506)
==15589==    by 0x40628D: hostname_Client() (client.cpp:221)
==15589==    by 0x4057E2: setup_Client(int) (client.cpp:55)
==15589==    by 0x4065F5: main (yichenwa_assignment1.cpp:77)
==15589==
```

My hostname_Client() code is:

```
char* hostname_Client(){
    ...
    char *hostname;
    strcpy(hostname,hostbuffer);
        ...
}
```

Comment: This code does not look like it should be the issue.  Can you post a [mre]?

Comment: I expect you corrupted the heap with some other part of your program.

Comment: @NathanOliver But it just stops in this for loop. Other parts I also use print to check and it works well. :( weird.

Comment: If you are sure it is stopping here, then the code somewhere before it is causing the problem.  You loop is well formed so the issue is somewhere else.  Making a [mre] will help you and us to find it.

Comment: Memory corruption (which this is a symptom of) can go undetected until long after you caused it, and later be detected in an apparently unrelated part of the program.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thank you sir, as it is a big project that I do not know how to make a minimal reproducible example...is that okay to share the project's github link?

Comment: No.  You need to pare the issue down into a [mre] and edit that into your question.  [This guidline](http://sscce.org/) can help you with that process.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thank you. I just add the code necessary in this post.

Comment: That is not a [mre].  You need to post something we can copy and paste into our own compilers and run it ourselves.

Comment: @Jambako  All that usage of `malloc`, etc. is not necessary in a C++ program.  Plus, you never check for `malloc` returning NULL, in addition to the memory leak.  There is too much that could go wrong, including this: `int s_len = s.length(); s.erase(s_len-5);` -- Why the magic number of `5`?  What if the string is less than 5 characters in length?

Comment: Have you run your program under valgrind (Linux) or PageHeap(Windows)? This should immediately flag any out-of-bounds accesses that are a precondition for memory corruption

Comment: @NathanOliver Sorry I mess up, but this project needs many .cpp to compile...It seems I cannot post too much code here:( I will use valgrind to check.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thank you sir, is that mean I do not need to use malloc in C++? I will add a check before erase, but s is always longer than 5...

Comment: @Botje thank you sir, I run the valgrind, but it does not give me many details...

Comment: @Jambako *but s is always longer than 5.* -- It's assumptions like this that will get you fired from a programming job.  You *always* verify that these assumptions are correct by writing code, not having faith in what someone may tell you.  Either you `assert` that the length is 5 or greater, `throw` an exception if the length is less than 5, etc.  What if you do this, and you find out one of your data is less than 5 characters, making it the reason why things are not working?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thank you, sir. I will correct this part to see if that can works!:D

Comment: Your use of strcpy in hostname_Client() is wrong for starters. <<Copies the C string pointed by source into the array pointed by destination, including the ...>> You have to allocate the return buffer. Perhaps you meant strdup(), which allocates using malloc()? In any case you need to verify that your gethostname call actually succeeded.

Comment: `char *hostname;
    strcpy(hostname,` is wrong and uses uninitialized pointer.

Comment: None of this is C++. This is plain C code. C++ code would look different, because C++ is not C and if you write in C++ as if it was C, you're wasting all the benefits that C++ gives you: you simply write C but call it C++ for some obscure reason. I'll not edit the tag to change it to C, but that's just because you mis-tagging it allowed us to point out that you're not writing C++. If you have ever heard the term "C/C++": it's usually a misnomer, because well written C++ code should look almost nothing like C code.

Comment: Why did you remove relevant code in the last edit? It makes the question unusable. Please revert that, or at least re-add relevant code so that the question will make sense again.

Comment: @KubaOber Sorry, sir. As this is a course project, I do not want to post too many codes. I keep the code with the bug part.

Comment: You have to post whatever code is needed to understand the question. Remember that there's essentially no way to permanently remove code from a stackoverflow question. If there's code that you can't post, then either prepare a reproducible example instead, or don't post the question at all. Also remember that the questions are not only for you: they are supposed to be useful for other people. If a question is useful to no one else, then it doesn't belong here either: why publicly post something that is of no use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char* hostname_Client(){
    char hostbuffer[1024]={0};
        gethostname(hostbuffer,sizeof(hostbuffer));
    char *hostname;
    strcpy(hostname,hostbuffer);
        return hostname;
}
```

You never initialize `hostname`, so it has some random value and doesn't point to anything. Then you pass its random value to `strcpy` and tell it to copy the string to some random location.

Since you're using C++, you may wish to consider using `std::string` instead of `char *` because it does most of the memory management for you.